# Valores de datagridview hacia vector

Tags: c#, windows-forms

compañeros alguno sabe como guardar valores de datadridview a un vector, dejo una imagen para que se hagan una idea.

lo que se quiere esque el usuario elija lo que desee en el primer datagrid y guardar seleccionados
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Se puede realizar de diferentes maneras, como están estructurados los datos, podrías compartirnos un poco mas de tu codigo, esta en clases o de qué manera piensas guardar los datos?

Comment: supongo que te refieres a un array , pues declaras el array => public string data =new string[count]; data[0]=datagrid.Column..., tambien podrias agregar otro tipo de datos como una clase

Answer (score 0):

Es muy simple si te ayudas con `linq`

```
var result = DataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>
                          .Where(r=> Convert.ToBoolean(r.Cells["Select"].Value))
                          .Select(r=> Convert.ToString(r.Cells["NTamiz"].Value))
                          .ToArray();
```

De esta forma puede pasar a un array de string los valores de una columna filtrando por la seleccion

Nota: recuerda definir correctamente los nombre de las columnas usando el Name de la columna del grid